# Apache Airflow - Operator for creating a Compute Engine?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-compute-engine

I would like to use Apache Airflow to start n Compute Engine VMs to execute a specific code on each, I started looking at the `ComputeEngineStartInstanceOperator` but it seems it only can start an existing VM, not create a new one.

Should I use the `BashOperator` or `PythonOperator` instead with something like: `gcloud compute instances create ...` or using Compute Engine python library ? or maybe Airflow is not the right tool for that kind of use ?

If I use the `BashOperator`, how can I manage the connection to GCP safely ? With `ComputeEngineStartInstanceOperator` it's pretty easy to connect.